# How to set children property in a canvas event handler?

Tags: c#, wpf

I've got a canvas and inside it will be a shape. That canvas has a `MouseLeftButtonDown` event handler. I then went to move the shape in the canvas to a new location however nothing happens.

Here is how the shape is added:

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Rectangle ShapeRect = new Rectangle() { Width=10,Height=10,Fill=Brushes.Blue};
        Canvas_1.Children.Add(ShapeRect);            
    }
```

Here is the event handler:

```
private void Canvas_1_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Canvas c = Canvas_1;
        var firstchild = c.Children[0];
        var RectCopy = c.Children.OfType<Rectangle>().FirstOrDefault();              

        Canvas.SetTop(RectCopy, Canvas.GetTop(RectCopy) + 500);
        Canvas.SetLeft(RectCopy, Canvas.GetLeft(RectCopy) + 500);
    }
```

I've tested the code and it has no errors and all lines run but clearly have no effect. I think it's due to the fact that `RectCopy` isn't `ShapeRect`. Any different solution or answers is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: If I understand the problem correctly, then the simplest solution would be to store the reference to `ShapeRect` in a field

Comment: You have to set initial values for Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top. Their default values are `double.NaN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following lines at the bottom of your Initialize method:

```
Canvas.SetTop(ShapeRect, 0);
Canvas.SetLeft(ShapeRect, 0);
```

When you get to your handler, the values of `Canvas.GetTop(...)` is `NaN`.

Comment: Thanks. It works now. I would've thought that the default value would be zero, zero.